# Transform effect not working in safari browser?

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

this code works perfectly on Mozilla and google chrome.but the is an problem occurs with safari browser.output is different on safari.
what code i ned to add in css or html.

HTML file:-

```
<div class="grid-70 prefix-15 mobile-grid-100 tablet-grid-100">            
                <span class="cta-btn cl-effect-18"><a href="#contact-section" class="drop1 cl-effect-18">Recent Update</a></span>
                <span class="cta-btn cl-effect-18"><a href="#contact-section" class="drop1 cl-effect-18">Who We are</a></span>
</div>
```

css file:-

```
  .cl-effect-18 a::before, .cl-effect-18 a::after {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      height: 2px;
      margin-top: -1px;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      content:'';
      z-index: -1;
      pointer-events: none;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s !important;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s!important;
      transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s !important;
  }
  .cl-effect-18 a::before {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
      transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  .cl-effect-18 a::after {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
      -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
      transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  .cl-effect-18 a:hover::before {
      transform: translateY(-30px) !important;
      -webkit-transform:translateY(-30px) !important;
      -webkit-transition:0.3s !important;
  }
  .cl-effect-18 a:hover::after {
      transform: translateY(30px) !important;
      -webkit-transform:translateY(30px) !important;
      -webkit-transition:0.3s !important;
  }
```

this is hover effect.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle of your question?

Comment: This should be it: http://jsfiddle.net/ArDD4/ but what exactly are we looking for?

Comment: Not sure exactly what is needed to solve the problem so I added color to visually see the behavior on hover. [jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/Td8ps/](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/Td8ps/) I recommend running it through [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/) and [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/) and make sure the necessary vendor prefixes are there and in the correct order.